# Organic Rails Data-Model with NoSQL Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nosql, dynamic-data, couchbase

I'd like to make full use of the organic character of a NoSQL document and build a dynamic data model which can grow, be changed, and is different for most datasets. Below is the model SomeRequest.rb with the code to set and get from Couchbase, but I can't get the function addOrUpdate(key, value) to work:

```
undefined method `each' for "0":String 

Completed 500 Internal Server
Error in 16ms NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "0":String): 
config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:7:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
```

Is the returning error. Is there a way to make this work, to add (or update existing) keys and save the document to the database afterwards?

```
class SomeRequest < Couchbase::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  # Couch Model
  define_model_callbacks :save

  attribute :session_id
  attribute :views, :default => 0
  attribute :created_at, :default => lambda { Time.zone.now }

  # iterate through attr keys and set instance vars
  def initialize(attr = {})
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
    unless attr.nil?
      attr.each do |name, value|
        setter = "#{name}="
        next unless respond_to?(setter)
        send(setter, value)
      end
    end
  end

  def addOrUpdate(key, value)
    self[key] = value
  end

  def save
    return false unless valid?
    run_callbacks :save do
      Couch.client.set(self.session_id, self)
    end
    true
  end

  def self.find(key)
    return nil unless key
    begin
      doc = Couch.client.get(key)
      self.new(doc)
    rescue Couchbase::Error::NotFound => e
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you like to use find, save and create methods from couchbase-model gem?

```
class Couchbase::Error::RecordInvalid < Couchbase::Error::Base
  attr_reader :record

  def initialize(record)
    @record = record
    errors = @record.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
    super("Record Invalid: #{errors}")
  end
end

class SomeRequest < Couchbase::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attribute :session_id
  attribute :views, :default => 0
  attribute :created_at, :default => lambda { Time.zone.now }

  validates_presence_of :session_id

  before_save do |doc|
    if doc.valid?
      doc
    else
      raise Couchbase::Error::RecordInvalid.new(doc)
    end
  end

  def initialize(*args)
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
    super
  end

end
```

And you might be right, it worth to add validation hooks by default, I think I will do it in next release. The example above is valid for release 0.3.0

What considering `updateOrAdd` I recommend you just use method `#save` and it will check if the key is persisted (currently by checking `id` attribute) and if the record doesn't have key yet, it will generate key and update it.

#### Update

In version `0.4.0` I added validation hooks into the gem, so the example above could be rewritten simpler.

```
class SomeRequest < Couchbase::Model
  attribute :session_id
  attribute :views, :default => 0
  attribute :created_at, :default => lambda { Time.zone.now }

  validates_presence_of :session_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still can only access attributes that are listed as 'attribute'. The idea is that I don't actually know what attributes there are in the document. I found a solution putting everything in a json object array which is named as 'attribute', but that's not perfect.

Comment: I was working with 0.1.0, from the official examples. 0.4.0 is much sleeker, thanks! But doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: ok. i see the problem, you'd like to define methods on the fly?